# Why "SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true" doesn't prevent the not confirmed Email from SignIn?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have configured MY Identity like this:

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(
               opts =>
               {
                   opts.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                   opts.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                   opts.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                   opts.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                   opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                   opts.Password.RequiredLength = 7;
               })
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I expect the users that their Email are not still confirmed be unable to Login to the system since I have already told `SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;`. But when I run the application I can Log with both two kind of users, the both that their Email are confirmed and the ones that their Email is not confirmed. So why `SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;` is not working in this case, is there any other config that I need to do?

**EDIT**: I just realized that I didn't check for Email confirmation in my Login method, something like this:

```
if (!await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))
```

So the main question, is the above line necessary even if I have already told `SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;`? I mean isn't the `SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;` enough? If it is not enough, what's it's usage at all?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question - Can you include the code that comes after where you've added `IsEmailConfirmedAsync`? I'm interested in the code that does the sign-in itself. e.g. Are you using `SignInManager`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin This is: `public async Task<AppUser> GetUserAsync(TokenRequestViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
                if (user == null && model.Username.Contains("@"))
                    user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Username);
                if (user == null || !await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password) ||
                    !await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))
                {
               Error
                }
        }`

Comment: @KirkLarkin So how can I use SignIn? Can you please show me an example or provide an answer?

Comment: That's a bit of a broad topic, but it's usually done with `SignInMangager.PasswordSignInAsync` when using Identity. `RequireConfirmedEmail` isn't used by `UserManager`, so if you are manually checking the password etc as your code above shows, you will just need to check explicitly like you're doing. If you can provide more context around what you do with the `AppUser` that is returned from your function, I might be able to help further.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using `opts.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;` is not enough. You need to add the check at login as well to see if the user can sign in using [SignInManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0), e.g.

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(login.Email);    
var canSignIn = await _signInManager.CanSignInAsync(user);
```